# I have a TypeError problem and cannot find the solution to fix it

Tags: typeerror

I am currently trying to code a Minecraft Ban Checker and had this issue for 2 days now and tried fixing it for 8h and cannot still find the problem. I know I am a dumb coder and I am a newbie and came to python 3 days ago. Just would like some help sorry for disturbing <3

[Code Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBGyz.png)

[Error Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svhcY.png)

Comment: edit your question to meet SO standards.

Comment: What do you mean edit your question?

Comment: There is a "Edit" at the bottom of the post.

Comment: Yeah but what do I edit? I am just asking for help I am a newbie.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you atleast know t he answer to my question?

Comment: I saw your answer from the "review queues" SO feature. Your answer do not apply to SO standards. You sould have read the link I had posted and edit your question. After that, the SO community will help you.